# Trying to add a menu to a TableViewer's header row (titles row)

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface

I am trying to add an action to a menu to the header (titles) of a TableViewer.

This is the code that I am using now:

```
    viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL 
                                         | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
    //...

    MenuManager manager = new MenuManager();
    viewer.getControl().setMenu(manager.createContextMenu(viewer.getControl()));


    manager.add(new Action("MENU ITEM TEXT") {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // get the current selection of the tableviewer
            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) viewer.getSelection();
            // do something
            if (selection.getFirstElement() instanceof MyObject)
                return;
            System.out.println("OK: "+selection.getFirstElement().getClass().getName());
        }
    });
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

**The problem is that the menu gets added to the entire TableViewer, not only to the header row.**
Because for the other rows I will need to use a different menu.
I have tryied to find a way of adding the action only to the top row (the titles row), but with no success so far.
So how can I add the menu only for the header?

Comment: There is no separate control for the column header so I don't think this can be done.

Comment: Maybe a MouseListener could be added on the table, then you could check if the selected row is not of any of the expected types. Then that would mean that it is the header. I need to try this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a `MouseListener` to the table, and you check for the following things:

1. Clicked button is mouse right-click.
2. The pointer of the event is located within the bounds of your table item (i.e. your first `TableItem` - you will use `table.getItem(Point)`).

If these conditions are met, you open the menu at mouse location.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet311.java)'s a snippet of how this can be done.